# Regex to strip trailing cashtags / hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a Javascript regex expression which will remove *trailing* hashtags or cashtags from a Tweet text.

---

**Example 1**

*Input:* This is a #test

*Output:* This is a

**Example 2**

*Input:* This is a #test but its much more #complicated $test $omg

*Output:* This is a #test but its much more

**Example 3**

*Input:* This example even #includes

a new #line and a http://www.link.com $wow

*Output:* This example even #includes
a new #line and a http://www.link.com

---

So far I've got `(^|\s)((#[a-z\d-]+)|(\$[a-z\d-]+))` - however, this strips all cashtags or hashtags in *any* position and incorrectly removes non-trailing tags.

How would I improve this regex to keep those cashtags / hashtags which aren't at the end?

Comment: You forgot to put the concept of "trailing" in the `regex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `regex` you use doesn't contain the information about matching the **trailing** tags.

Try this one:

```
/(?:\s*[#$][a-z\d-]+)+$/i
```

**What it means:**

```
/                # regex delimiter
(?:              # start of a non-capturing group
    \s*          # zero or more white spaces
    [#$]         # one of '#' or '$'
    [a-z\d-]+    # one or more of: letters, digits, dash
)                # end of the group
+                # previous expression (the group) one or more times
$                # the end of the string
/                # regex delimiter
i                # ignore case (to let [a-z] match both lowercase and uppercase)
```

Each group matches one tag and the space characters in front of it (if any). The end of string anchor (`$`) ensures the expression matches only when the groups are at the end of the string.

Comment: Awesome. This pretty much works, but for some reason it doesn't work for the following example: "For some reason this doesn't work #CFTC #bitcoin $btc $eth $ada" any ideas?

Comment: @p_mcp It's not working because of `a-z` use `A-z` or `A-Za-z`. https://regex101.com/r/xgzqyK/2

Comment: `#CFTC` uses uppercase letters, the `regex` uses only lowercase. You can add `A-Z` after `a-z` in the second range or you can use the [`i` flag (ignore case)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags).

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
/(^|\s)((#[a-z\d-]+)|(\$[a-z\d-]+))\s*$/
```

should match only at the end - look at the `\s*$` at the end, it matches at the end of the string, and accepts trailing whitespace after the tags. If there is no whitespace at the end, you can drop the `\s*` part.

Comment: Almost works, but this only matches the very last cashtag / hashtag and not multiple trailing tags